# Dynamically create radio buttons

Tags: java

I would like to dynamically create radio buttons in a second frame and be able to change the background color of my radio buttons based on the input once a button is selected. My problem is I can create the second frame, however, the radio buttons are not created. Appreciate any help!

Here's my code

```
public class ColorRadioButtons extends ReadStoreShow{
    private JFrame f = new JFrame("Colors");
    public ColorRadioButtons() {
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
        panel2.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));
        ButtonGroup radioButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();

        for (int i=0; i<subListOfColors.size(); i++) {
            Colors a = subListOfColors.get(i);
            String s = a.getColorName();
            JRadioButton jrb = new JRadioButton(s);
            radioButtonGroup.add(jrb);
            panel2.add(jrb);
        }
        add(panel2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        f.pack();
        f.setTitle("Colors Radio Buttons");
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is something wrong (not related to the problem from the text) on this line:  `if (number >= 10 || number <= 20)`.  This is, if I'm not mistaken, the same as `if(true)` or no `if` at all. I think what you meant was `&&` instead of `||`.